# How to find a row does not contain value in another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this :

```
Id    | Value1 | Value2  
1     |   x    |   2  
2     |   x    |   3  
3     |   x    |   7  
4     |   y    |   3  
5     |   z    |   1  
6     |   z    |   7  
7     |   c    |   5  
8     |   c    |   6
```

How I can get the 'Value1' that doesn't contain value 7 in column 'Value2'

So, the result should be :
y
c

Thanks.

Comment: `select val1 from yourtable where val2<>7`? Or is that too easy?

Comment: @Drew I believe this may have been wrongfully marked as a duplicate. Look at the result-set. If this was a simple "Where not = 7", then it would return X and Z, not just Y and C. OP was not super clear in this, however PaulF pointed out the same error in my own answer below.

Comment: @Santi - thanks I was just about to make that comment & have marked the question for re-opening

Comment: @MarcB: too easy - OP wants to eliminate ALL rows where value1 is x or z, because some of those rows contain value2 = 7. So not simply selecting only rows not equal to 7

Comment: @Santi this is a classic case of a question that does not benefit this site. Ergo we move it toward deletion

Comment: @Drew: apart from the OP not showing any attempts to solve the problem - why does it not benefit the site. It is not a duplicate problem & as you pointed out to Santi - what would seem an obvious solution has problems.

Comment: Everyone is free to votes as they see fit @PaulF. Usually we don't have to write "imo" after every sentence. It is assumed.

Comment: @PaulF I reopened it :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

As pointed out by PaulF in the comments below, I may have misunderstood your question. Try something like this instead...

```
SELECT DISTINCT Value1 
FROM MyTable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Value1 FROM MyTable b WHERE b.Value1 = a.Value1 AND b.Value2 = 7)
```

Comment: Wont your query return x,y, z & c - OP wants to eliminate x & z because they have values containing 7

Comment: @PaulF Oh man, you may be correct! I misunderstood the question I suppose. I'll edit.

Comment: @PaulF Perhaps this is better!

Comment: Beat me to it again - I had DISTINCT in the subquery too, not needed in the sample data - but maybe would improve efficiency in a large table

Comment: as you don't know the schema, this could be a dangerous use of `NOT IN` which should be avoided as such

Comment: @drew Why is that? Genuinely curious.

Comment: @Drew Appreciate that, very interesting read. I've edited my answer to be a `NOT EXISTS` instead. Does this same logic apply to other SQL-types as well, like T-SQL/SQL Server?